# QGIS - Unable to get OSM data on re-opening project

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins

I have now successfully got OSM maps to import as I would like, but if I save the project then later re-open, I always get a bad layer message and I have to reload the OSM once the project is open.

How can I save the datasource reference with the project so I don't get this every time?

Comment: Is this problem one that arises when you import OSM data from an *.osm file using the OpenStreetMap plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the imported data into a spatialite database, and add the spatialite layers to your project. Then you can delete the Openstreetmap layer from your project.

Openstreetmap data comes in a special format, and has to be "translated" to GIS standards. By saving to a spatial database you only have to do that once.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without importing into a database? If not, can you point me in the direction of a 'how to' for this process. I have MS SQL 2008.

Comment: You can also use ESRi shapefilles. Just right-click the layer and save as. I have no experience with MS SQL2008. Spatialite support is built-in with Qgis. Create new Spatialite layers for points, lines and polygons, make them editable, and copy and paste the data from existing layers to the new ones. If your project area is country-wide, the best solution is a PostgreSQL database with Postgis extension. Openstreetmap has a good importer for that called osm2pgsql. You find help for that in OSM wiki. Quantum GIS can query that Postgis database easily.

Comment: That's great, using ESRi shapefiles is just what I wanted to know. I don't really need to use a database as the area I am working with is quite small (about 100km2).